# Disallow only whitespaces or show alert only if the user types letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, whitespace, removing-whitespace

The user is supposed to enter some information in the textarea (inside p tag in my case) which is mainly strings. However, I want to stop the user from only entering whitespaces[continuous multiple whitespaces], on which I will alert him asking to type something meaningful. How do I check for this condition? Is `"if there are no normal alphabets; then alert blahblah"` a working logic? How do I code this?

### Code so far

```
$("#saveText").click(function() {
  var grabbed = $(".froala-element p").text();
  if (grabbed === "") {
    alert("No cheating :) Please type something.");
  } else {
    alert(grabbed);
  }
});
```

This is all I got so far. A jQuery solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) against a regular expression that represents only whitespace (`/^\s*$/`):

```
$("#saveText").click(function() {
  var grabbed = $(".froala-element p").text();

  if (/^\s*$/.test(grabbed)) {
    alert("No cheating :) Please type something.");
  } else {
    alert(grabbed);
  }
});
```

This handles regular spaces, tabs, newlines, etc., as well as the case where there's no input.

The regular expression itself decomposes as follows:

```
^    Beginning of the string
\s   Any whitespace character
*    Zero or more occurrences of previous
$    End of the string
```

You could alternatively turn the test around and check for the presence of at least one non-whitespace character using `/\S/`, which is probably slightly more efficient.

Comment: Awesome!! This works. I now know why we should learn regular expressions, even though I find it very difficult to master. Thanks for the relevant link.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian Regular expressions can indeed be difficult to master, but knowing the basics will already get you pretty far.

Comment: I never thought the "other-way-around" thinking was possible to implement. Thanks on that one. It sure is a good idea. But that I will figure myself out as I have been asking too much already LOL.

Comment: if (grabbed.trim() === "") does the same thing, and is much simpler.

Comment: @Vizkos That's indeed a little bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is in 'p' tag, your code is all right, if it is textarea, it should be:

```
var grabbed = $(".froala-element textarea").val();
```

Comment: I am so sorry. It is my mistake. It is in `p` tag. I just wanted to give a clear picture of the situation. And hence wrote that way. Thanks though. This will help someone for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen for 'blur' and 'paste' event to make sure blank characters aren't entered by user, as show below:-

http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/024jvy5h/

```
$('#type_something').on('paste', function(event){
var element = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    var text = $(element).val();
    if(text.trim().length <= 0) {
        alert('Sorry, paste something else, not empty string');
        $(element).val('');
    }
}, 100);
```

});

```
$('#type_something').on('blur', function(event){
var element = this;
var text = $(element).val();
if(text.trim().length <= 0) {
    alert('Sorry, type something else, not blank characters');
    $(element).val('');
}
```

});